# Transparent PNG has grey border in Chrome and IE, invisible in FireFox

Tags: html, png, invisible

why does the PNG have a grey border in Google Chrome and IE?

Also, why isn't it visible in FireFox?

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nr5tb/)

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inline Border</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .inline-image {
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAfklEQVR42mNgoDZITk4WosiAtLS0M6mpqb1Amp9cAy4B8X8gfpWenp5MiQEwfB6IbSgxAIaXArEcJQaA8Ddg+NQVFhZykmsADG8MDQ1lJseA5wQDFocBP0FRm5WVxUNOGGwEJi4VcmLhKtC5HuSkg8NA5+bjDCRCAG8UDUoAAIw8kVdwMG+3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) 0px 0px no-repeat no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="inline-image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use css reset or just add border:0; to html in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to user background-image, you should use div tag.

Otherwise, If you want to user img tag in this stituation, you should add src attribute with transparent image.

Answer (score 2):

Check this jsfiddle:http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nr5tb/7/.I Hope you got your answer from this.

You have an img element that doesn't have a src attribute, but it does have a background-image style applied.
I'd say that the gray border is the 'placeholder' for where the image would be, if you'd specified a src attribute.
If you don't want a 'foreground' image, then don't use an img tag as I mention in my jsfiddle

Comment: You can use the same css just change the container from img to div. And adjust css to meet div needs eg text-align:center doesn't work for div but does for img.

Answer (score -1):

You need add one more style in css

```
.inline-image {

    display: block;
            }
```

or you need to change the `<img>` tag to `<div>`

Comment: @Stefan Nope it works.i checked in Fiddle. you click your fiddle link and give " display: block " in your style and click run it will display.

Comment: I think @Ravichandran you vote yourself you have 4 fake account as I check you always get minimum 4 votes in all cases as this answer didn't seem to get more vote as `display:block` is not working

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava kindly read the above comment. and do the same you will get clear. don't assume yourself anything.

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava just now i saw your profile. it was blocked as you mentioned. why you are so jealous about other profiles. and i know you down vote my questions also. this is not good.

Comment: @Ravichandran don't comment here just remove all comment as it for discussion of question.I am happy I can't post question it make me more to think :)